# Cannot start keycloak in docker with letsencrypt certificates

Tags: docker, keycloak, lets-encrypt

I can run Keycloak with the following command

```
./bin/kc.sh start-dev \
--https-certificate-file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/$HOSTNAME/cert.pem \
--https-certificate-key-file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/$HOSTNAME/privkey.pem \
--hostname=$HOSTNAME
```

Works as expected

On the same computer, I try to run using Docker

```
docker run -p 80:8080 -p 443:8443 \
  -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=change_me \
  -e JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="$JAVA_OPTS_APPEND" \
  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest \
  start-dev \
  --https-certificate-file=/ect/letsencrypt/live/$HOSTNAME/cert.pem \
  --https-certificate-key-file=/ect/letsencrypt/live/$HOSTNAME/privkey.pem \
  --hostname=$HOSTNAME
```

It fails

```
2022-12-23 23:11:59,784 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2022-12-23 23:11:59,785 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: /ect/letsencrypt/live/keycloak.fhir-poc.hcs.us.com/cert.pem
2022-12-23 23:11:59,787 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) Key material not provided to setup HTTPS. Please configure your keys/certificates.
```

Any suggestions besides a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer
letsencrypt certificates in the "live" folder are symlinks to the "archive" folder and I needed a custom docker image for keycloak to mount my certificates.  So I followed the keycloak docs for creating a custom docker image and started a container with that image

Following

https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers

https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#where-are-my-certificates

to build a custom image and change the cert permissions

Dockerfile

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest as builder

ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=root
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=change_me

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
COPY kc-export.json /opt/keycloak/kc-export.json
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh import --file /opt/keycloak/kc-export.json
VOLUME [ "/opt/keycloak/certs" ]

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]
```

Then start the container

```
 docker run -p 8443:8443 \
  -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=change_me \
  -e JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="$JAVA_OPTS_APPEND" \
  my-keycloak-image:latest \
  start-dev \
  --https-certificate-file=/opt/keycloak/certs/live/$HOSTNAME/cert.pem \
  --https-certificate-key-file=/opt/keycloak/certs/live/$HOSTNAME/privkey.pem \
  --hostname=$HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is based on the directory linked structure of letsencrypt in linux and the permissions to access these files.

Letsencrypt linked directory structure works like:

- /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your-domain/*.pem -> /etc/letsencrypt/archive/<your-domain/*.pem

1. The problem is the link from the live to the archive folder/file.
2. The permissions are mostly not correct.

A **quick-fix** is create a *cert-mirror* and copy the related files from /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your-domain/*.pem

- to a new cert folder like /opt/cert
- change permissions in /opt/cert to 777: chmod 777 -R /opt/certs
- create a cron.monthly job in /etc/cron.monthly which copy the files to /opt/certs + change permissions correctly every month that your certs mirror always up-to-date

This will make your example working. Please keep in mind that permissions like 777 are let everyone access this file. You should use the correct permissions in productive environment.